Почему при запуске проекта возникает ошибка "IDE error occurred"?
После перехода на Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1 появилась ошибка при запуске проекта.
Так всё компилирует – ошибок нет.
На что стоит обратить внимание?
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: getGradleProjectPath(Module: 'Test_billing_v3.app') == null
        at com.android.tools.idea.projectsystem.gradle.GradleModuleSystem.getGradleProjectPath(GradleModuleSystem.kt:580)
        at com.android.tools.idea.projectsystem.gradle.GradleModuleSystem.getDynamicFeatureModules(GradleModuleSystem.kt:565)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.variant.view.BuildVariantTableModelKt.buildVariantTableModelRows(BuildVariantTableModel.kt:124)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.variant.view.BuildVariantTableModelKt.access$buildVariantTableModelRows(BuildVariantTableModel.kt:1)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.variant.view.BuildVariantTableModel$Companion.create(BuildVariantTableModel.kt:86)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.variant.view.BuildVariantTableModel.create(BuildVariantTableModel.kt)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.variant.view.BuildVariantView.updateContents(BuildVariantView.java:139)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.variant.view.BuildVariantView.updateContents(BuildVariantView.java:160)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.variant.conflict.ConflictSet$showSelectionConflicts$1.run(ConflictSet.kt:55)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:27)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:229)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:22)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread$lambda$1(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:184)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:183)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:836)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:122)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1162)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:78)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:119)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:696)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$16(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithoutImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:117)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:73)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:357)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:843)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke$lambda$0(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.lambda$run$0(WriteIntentReadAction.java:24)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteIntentReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:910)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.compute(WriteIntentReadAction.java:55)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.run(WriteIntentReadAction.java:23)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$10(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:397)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

